How can I search for a message that has a certain text string in a channel using discord.js?
I basically am building a discord bot that needs me to search a specific channel of mine for a string like find every message that has the word "silver" in it. Is there a specific way that I may achieve this?
I tried searching for a certain method in the docs and on this site but the only thing I found was I have to get all that data and store it into an array, then loop through that data to get what im searching for. Is this the only way I can do this? Or are there other paths I can follow?

This method allows you to fetch channel messages which you can then search as you wish. The only other way to read message content would be to listen for the MessageCreate event.

Thank you but does this method have any drawbacks? Like a limit to how much it can count? is there also a way to get the message data?

You can fetch 100 channel messages at once. What do you mean message data?
